# How to detect when console system time was changed since the game was last run, without a net connection?

Tags: c++, timer, time, playstation4, playstation5

As an example of the behaviour I want to implement in my game, look at Bloons TD 5 on the PS4/PS5 and its Daily Chest Reward. If you disconnect the internet and change the date and time and play the game, it still knows the last time the game was opened.

How could my game know when it was last opened if the system time is changed and the console is disconnected from the internet?

Comment: Are you saying if I open Bloons TD5 and claim today's daily chest reward, then close the game, unplug the network cable, and set my system time forward to tomorrow before re-launching Bloons, it still "knows" it's the same day and does not give me tomorrow's daily chest early? Or does it only block me if I try to set the system time backward, to re-clain today's daily chest again?

Comment: Cant you just get the time in UTC+0:00, and then even if the timezone changes, your always using the same timezone.

Comment: @Pow, this question is not about time zones. This is about players deliberately changing the system time to arbitrary values in order to cheat around game systems that are meant to give rewards or release timed content on a specific schedule. See "Time Travel" in Animal Crossing as a famous example.

Comment: You could consider using a remote service (API) to check if there is a reward to claim? That means nobody gets a reward without internet access, but it allows you to decide if that user is allowed to receive a reward based on a clock you're in full control of.